# SQLite: Use of Aliases in Calculations

Tags: sqlite

Can an Alias be used in a calculated column in SQLite?  I have the following query:

```
SELECT
    dpTicker AS Ticker,
    max(dpDate) AS Datum,
    dpClose AS Price,
    (SELECT
        sum(div)
    FROM Dividends
    WHERE
        divTicker = DP1.dpTicker
        AND strftime('%Y', divDate) = strftime('%Y', date('now','-1 Year'))) 
    AS sumDiv,
    (SELECT
        sum(div)
    FROM Dividends
    WHERE
        divTicker = DP1.dpTicker
        AND strftime('%Y', divDate) = strftime('%Y', date('now','-1 Year')))/dpClose*100
     AS divYield    
FROM DailyPrices AS DP1
GROUP BY dpTicker
ORDER BY divYield DESC;
```

As you can notice in the above query, the code for sumDiv is repeated twice.  I have been searching how to use aliases in calculated column, however, my attempts have been unfruitful.

Direct use of the alias (sumDiv) in a calculation results in an error message.  I have read that wrapping the alias around a SELECT statement should work:

```
(SELECT sumDiv)/dpClose AS divYield
```

This attempt results in the same error:

```
bash-3.2$ sqlite3 myShares < Queries/test.sql
Error: near line 1: no such column: sumDiv
```

Can aliases be used in calculation, or do I have to repeat the code twice?

Thanks in advance for any feedback, and helping to crawl up the SQLite learning curve.

Best regards,

GAM

Answer (score 2):

The SQL standard says that aliases are not visible in other parts of the same SELECT clause.

> <sub>All problems in computer science can be solved by another level of indirection.
>
>   — David Wheeler</sub>

Just move the computation into a subquery:

```
SELECT sumDiv,
       sumDiv / dpClose AS divYield
FROM (SELECT (SELECT sum(div)
              FROM Dividends
              WHERE ...
             ) AS sumDiv,
             ...
      FROM DailyPrices
      ...);
```